# Changing a hard-coded prop on an imported component doesn't trigger HMR

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I've been playing around with vue-next (version 3 of vuejs) and ran into an issue with HMR. Here's a rundown of my environment and the problem but:

**TL;DR; - Hard coded props don't trigger HMR on an imported component**

Some essential info about the environment. Any files I didn't include are the default from the vue-next webpack preview: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next-webpack-preview

**Package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --env.prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.0-beta.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^16.0.0-alpha.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

- Create a new "component", let's call it Surface. It accepts an elevation prop that will be used to compute a CSS variable named `--elevation`.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Surface",
  props: {
    elevation: {
      type: Number as () => 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    console.log(props.elevation);
    const cssProps = computed(() => ({
      "--elevation": `${props.elevation}em`
    }));

    return { cssProps };
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div :style="cssProps>Hello, world!{{ elevation }}</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: var(--elevation);
}
</style>
```

- Consume the `Surface` component in another `.vue` file:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

import { Surface } from "./Surface.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: { Surface },
  setup() {

    return { };
  }
});

<template>
  <div :style="cssProps">Hello, world!{{ elevation }}</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
:root {
  --elevation: 0rem;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: var(--elevation);
}
</style>

</script>

<template>
  <Surface :elevation="3" />
</template>
```

- Modify the elevation prop.

**Expected**
Hot Module Replacement triggers and re-renders the `Surface` component with the adjusted elevation prop.

**Result**
Hot Module Replacement does not trigger on change, but the component will update on reload; as to be expected.

This seems to only be an issue with a hard-coded prop. When I use `const elevation = ref(0);` it works fine.

**Screenshots**
Rendered
[image]

Comment: Can you share your project's file configuration? Sometimes there's a mismatch in file names and HMR doesn't pick updates.

Comment: What do you mean by file configuration? I'm using the webpack preview repo with TS added in too. I did bump some package versions up, but it seems that making a change to the file that accepts the prop and saving triggers the HMR, just not save from the component that consumes it.